# In C#, which is better/faster? A list of lists or an array of arrays (jagged array)?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I ask this question out of sheer curiosity.  I don't have any actual code to ponder over.

Is there a best-case scenario for using a jagged array instead of a list of lists, and vice versa?

Comment: A List of Lists is also "jagged" so this question is effectively asking, "Which is better/faster? A list or an array?" Perhaps you mean to compare "jagged" arrays with n-dimensional ("dense") arrays? (And the question still lacks context to make it a "practical" issue.)

Comment: @pst is correct. Also, lists are internally implemented using an array. I think the answer to your question is "it depends".

Comment: Without context, it's difficult to answer.  Which is better or faster depends on what operations you are performing and the typical size of your data.

Comment: @Matt Can you make up an example to show how it might be better to use one approach over the other?  And then vice versa?

Comment: @SimpleCoder Can you make up an example to show how it might be better to use one approach over the other?  And then vice versa?

Comment: @phan: I can't think of any examples. Like I said (and others have said), it depends on the situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a `List<T>` **is** an array, just a wrapped in a class so it can reallocate and resize it at will. So otherwise performance between the two can be considered identical - only use `List<List<T>>` if you need to resize either dimension - don't forget that whenever you resize the 0th dimension you'll need to construct new instances in the 1st dimension, which can be expensive.

You forgot n-dimensional arrays (i.e. `T[,]`). However, due to a quirk in .NET's bounds-checking these are actually slower than jagged arrays or single-dimensional-user-managed arrays, which is a complete mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Jagged arrays and lists of lists have the same relative merits as plain lists and arrays:

The main advantage of a `List<T>` is that you can grow and shrink it.  However it may take up a lot of extra space in memory because it generally keeps a bunch of extra space in its backing store so that it doesn't have to re-allocate a new array every single time it grows.

The main advantage of an array is that it's compact - it has exactly enough space to store the number of elements that are in it, and no more.  But its size is static; if you need to add a new item to it you must either replace an existing item or manually create a bigger array and copy data into it.

In terms of speed they should behave identically, to any practical extent.  `List<T>` uses an array for its backing store, so it *might* be slightly slower than an equivalent array because of the extra layer of indirection.  But I wouldn't assume that without careful measurements - whether and to what extent it does is the kind of thing that could change with different versions of the framework or the CLR.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a `List<T>` is more flexible where as a `T[]` is more inter-operable.  For example, if I wanted to construct a list of an unknown size, I would use a `List<T>`.  If I was returning a list from a web-service I would use a `T[]`.

I know I am referring to single-dimension lists here, but the same practice would apply for multiple dimensions.